# How to print JSON response from reddit API

Tags: python, json, python-requests, reddit

Here is my code:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CLIENT_ID = 'mb_cSXkFXaFE6Q2QrWmc2w'
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

with open('pw.txt', 'r') as f:
pw = f.read()
data = {
'grant_type': 'password',
'username': 'brandonbann',
'password': pw
}
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'MyAPI/0.0.1'}
res = requests.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',
auth=HTTPBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID, SECRET_KEY), data=data, headers=headers)
print(res)
```

Running this in the command line returns

```
Response [200]
```

, which I believe is a good sign, however, I would like it to print the json. I tried:

```
print(res.json())
```

but am met with: `'error': 'invalid_grant'`. Googling this error didn't help me much. I expect the result to be similar to:

```
{'access_token': xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'token_type': 'bearer',
 'expires_in': 3600,
 'scope': '*'}
```

Comment: Your code is "correct" for an unauthenticated site... Your error is just the server's response.

Comment: You may want to try adding `'Content-Type':'application/json'` to the headers

Answer (score 0):

Since its not a json response, you should try this

```
res.text
```